# How to bind outlook add-in dropdown?

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook, outlook-addin

I want to bind a dropdown which is in ribbon.xml file like below, I am not sure how to add items in dropdown. I tried with  onAaction event but it is not even firing. any idea how I can proceed with this?

```
<group id="Family" label="Family Group">
      <dropDown id="drpFamily" label="Family" showImage="false" onAction="BindDropdown"  />
      </group>
```

Answer (score 0):

All Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) controls are described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Also you may find the [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.

See [How to dynamically add items in Ribbon dropdown](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/013389cd-0dde-479e-99b1-62991c1b6004/how-to-dynamically-add-items-in-ribbon-dropdown?forum=vsto) and [Adding items to RibbonDropDown at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644004/adding-items-to-ribbondropdown-at-runtime) for more information.